# python text substitution 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, string, dictionary, text, substitution

I want to substitute a variable name in an expression. However I get the error that str is not callable
Here is my example

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
raw_data = {'student_name': ['M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4', 'M5', 'M6', 'M7', 'M8', 'M9', 'M10', 'M11', 'M12'], 
        'vocal_grade': ['R', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'R', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', np.NaN]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['student_name', 'vocal_grade'])

dict_sam_vocal = {'R': 8, 'X': 5, 'Y': 6, 'Z': 7}
```

This works fine

```
x = 'vocal'
df[x+'_score'] = df[x+"_grade"].map(dict_sam_vocal)
```

When I try to parametrize dictionary , I get the following error

```
df[x+'_score'] = df[x+"_grade"].map("dict_sam_"+x)

pandas/src/inference.pyx in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:63043)()

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: `.map()` takes a function as an argument. `"dict_sam_"+x` is a string. The contents of the string might be the same as the name of a function, but that doesn't connect it to the function in any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you passed a string to `map` which is expecting a dictionary in your case. In order for the map to treat it as a dictionary instead of a string, use `eval` to evaluate the string and get back the corresponding dictionary:

```
x = 'vocal'
df[x+'_score'] = df[x+"_grade"].map(eval("dict_sam_"+x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `dict_sam_vocal` using a string like this:

`df[x+'_score'] = df[x+"_grade"].map(globals()["dict_sam_"+x])`